# What's the meaning of the phrasal verb "sped out"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

As usual, I try to practice English grammar, vocabulary and speaking skills through some exercises. Today I've got stuck with the following phrasal verb "**sped out**" and after a Google search was not able to grasp properly its meaning.

Here's the complete sentence:

> Through an inadvertent error, the guided missile **sped out** of control.

I suppose the meaning sounds like "went out of control", or "stopped working properly" but not sure if this is the right definition though. Google mostly offers definition for "speed up". Or maybe it means that it became faster and unable to control?

Comment: The **out** belongs with the phrase **out of control**. So, as you surmise, it went **out of control** at speed.

Comment: Means this is not a phrasal verb?

Comment: @CarlosFlorian Correct. The verb in your sentence is simply "sped."

Comment: Thanks! For a non-native speaker it looked like a phrasal verb. I learned something new today.